# Java division is not doing what I expected..

Tags: java, division

I've searched a bit, and still can't find an answer for this.

I am computing a formula for *`distances between tree nodes`*, and in my test case, my formula takes the number of leaves in **`node i`**, and divides it by the number of leaves in **`node i`** + the number of leaves in **`node j`**.
These give me `1 and 2 respectively`, since both **`i`** and **`j`** have one leaf each.

***My issue is that when I divide 1 by 2, I get zero.***

All these numbers are doubles, so I don't see what the problem is. . .

Here is my code:

```
formula1 = ((newNode.getLeftChild().getNumLeafs()) / (newNode.getLeftChild().getNumLeafs() + newNode.getRightChild().getNumLeafs()));
```

Comment: So `getNumLeafs()` returns a double? - sounds pretty odd!

Comment: Have you tried logging what those values are? `System.out.printf("Left Count = %d, Right Count = %d\n", newNode.getLeftChild().getNumLeafs(), newNode.getRightChild().getNumLeafs());`

Comment: Are you sure you're dealing with doubles? It is rare for a method like getNumXXX() to return anything other than an int.

Comment: try: formula1 = (double)(newNode.getLeftChild().getNumLeafs()) /            (double)((newNode.getLeftChild().getNumLeafs() + newNode.getRightChild().getNumLeafs()))); if it works, then your assumption was invalid

Comment: Reduce your question by substituting the values returned by each `getNumLeafs()` call.

Comment: Please add the definitions of the variables and show the type of return value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
formula1 = ((double)(newNode.getLeftChild().getNumLeafs()) / (double)(newNode.getLeftChild().getNumLeafs() + (double)newNode.getRightChild().getNumLeafs()));
```

`getNumLeafs()` is probably returning an int value

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you.